# How to query Rails / ActiveRecord model based on custom model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, rails-activerecord

**Disclaimer**: I'm relatively new to rails.

I have a custom method in my model that I'd like to query on. The method, called 'active?', returns a boolean. What I'd really like to do is create an ActiveRecord query of the following form:

```
Users.where(:active => true)
```

Naturally, I get a "column does not exist" when I run the above as-is, so my question is as follows:

How do I do the equivalent of the above, but for a custom method on the model rather than an actual DB column?

Comment: What does that active? method use to determine if it's true?

Comment: Whether archived != false && whether Time.now falls between start_date and end_date on a parent table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the active? method, you would have a scope to help find items that match.

Something like this...

```
def self.active
  joins(:parent_table).where(:archived => false).where("? BETWEEN parent_table.start_date AND parent_table.end_date ", Time.now)
end
```

And, you should be able to do this

```
def active?
  User.active.exists?(self)
end
```

If you would like to reuse this scope for the instance test.

Comment: Is this in addition to the existing `active?` method? Also, when I call this later, do I use the `Users.where(:active => true)` syntax or something else?

Comment: My guess would be yes to the former, probably just `User.active` for the latter?

Comment: You would call User.active (to get a list), use this with other scopes and @user.active? to test the instance.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be by using the `select` method with your exiting model method.

```rb
Users.select{|u| u.active}
```

This will return an array so you won't be able to use Active Record Query methods on it. To return the results as an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object, you can use the `where` function to query instances that have matching ids:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.active
    active_array = self.select{|r| r.active?}
    active_relation = self.where(id: active_array.map(&:id))
    return active_relation
  end

end
```